# Angular CLI and angular 4 not work ng serve

Tags: angular

When I do ng serve  I get this result

```
angular\router\@angular\router.es5.jsError: No module factory available   for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
at Compilation.addModuleDependencies
node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:264
                           if(_this.profile) {
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
at factoryCallback
```

angular-cli

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    ...

Comment: using for existing app or new app

Comment: existing app, in my machine work fine, it is in other machine after git clone and npm install, it has same cli that my machine

Comment: I confuse the update to the install package - `npm install @angular/cli -g` every time and I get random errors until I remember it's not angular-cli

Comment: it changes to @angular/cli before it's calls angular-cli

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by doing the following steps:
1- remove webpack from package.json
2- delete node_modules folder
3- install webpack globally using the following commands:
     npm install webpack -g
     npm install webpack-dev-server -g
4- run npm install

Note: If (npm start) generates error try to remove (package-lock.json), delete node_modules, and run "npm install" again

Answer (score 0):

As angular 4 is out, use `ng new` to  generate new angular project as it is mentioned in the change log of angular cli and then try it

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

or you must update your angular cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment,

In the another machine, install Angular-CLI by using

```
npm install angular-cli -g
```

Then try running your app through `ng serve`

Comment: it has installed cli same that mine cli-1.0.0

Comment: that is not the problem

Comment: thats the problem delete the npm cache and reinstall the cli again. Also did you give a npm i after moving the app to another computer?

Comment: CLI update, now for install angular-cli, it is this way npm install -g @angular/cli, it changes from angular-cli to @angular/cli